# Having trouble with the chronological order in my code

Tags: python

I'm doing a queue simulation that handles one customer at a time.

- The time that one errand takes is **two minutes**,
- and the customers enters the post office at random with the
  probability **0.2/minute**.
- The customers errands are also randomized.

> My problem is that the time that it takes to handle the customer WHEN
>   there is a queue, isn't correct.

I'm thinking of taking the last customers `out_time` and make that the next customers `in_time` (the time that he start getting served by the clerk).

for example: 
time 1: Customer 1 comes in with 2 errand(s).
time 1: Customer 2 comes in with 1 errand(s).
time 5: Customer 1 leaves.
**time 6: Customer 2 leaves.** <--- wrong.
should be time 7:  Customer 2 leaves.

```
import random as rn

class Post_office:
    def __init__(self):
        self.customer_in_queue = 0

        self.clock = 0
        self.open= 540  #opens 9am
        self.close = 1080 #closes 18pm
        self.time_in = self.generate_incoming()
        self.time_out = float('inf')
        self.customernr_in = 0
        self.customernr_out = 0
        self.total_wait = 0


    def add_time(self):
        t_event = min(self.time_in, self.time_out)

        self.total_wait += self.customer_in_queue*(t_event-self.clock)
        self.clock = t_event

        if self.time_in <= self.time_out:
            self.handle_in_custom()
        else:
            self.handle_out_custom()


    def handle_in_custom(self):
        self.customer_in_queue +=1
        self.customernr_in +=1
        text = ''

        errands = self.generate_errands()

        if self.customer_in_queue <=1:
            self.time_out = self.clock + (errands*2)
            text = 'and is immediately served'
        else:
            text = ' queuing as '+str(self.customer_in_queue)
        self.time_in = self.clock + self.generate_incoming()

        print('time', str(self.clock), 'customer came', str(self.customernr_in),'in with',
              str(errands),'errands', text)

    def handle_out_custom(self):
        self.customer_in_queue -= 1
        self.customernr_out += 1
        text = ''

        if self.customer_in_queue > 0:
            self.clock = self.time_out + self.generate_errands()
            text = self.clock
        else:
            self.time_out = float('inf')
            text = self.clock

        print('Time', str(text), ' customer', str(self.customernr_out),'left')

    def generate_incoming(self):

        return int(rn.expovariate(0.2))

    def generate_errands(self):
        rand = rn.random()
        errands = 1                                                     
        chance = 0.5                                                         
        while chance > rand:
                errands = errands + 1                                       
                chance = chance / 2                                          

        return errands

p = Post_office()

for minute in range(p.clock, p.close):
    minute +=1
    p.add_time()

print('Total amount of customers:', str(p.customernr_in), 'Total wait per customer:',str(p.total_wait/p.customernr_in))
```

Comment: Provide the code that you tried. And also add inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: The question has been edited and updated with the code.